# Visual Studio cannot load symbols from a static library used on a module of the main application

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, static-libraries, debug-symbols

I have a static library L used in a module M (a static library too) and the module is linked against the main application A. If I debug the main application A, I can't step into the code or see symbols of the library L because Visual Studio doesn't load its symbols. (I am using VS 2013)

The library L is built on another machine, with a local path like D:\thirdparty\L\... and I can debug fine on this machine, see the symbols and step into the code, but not on a machine getting this library separately.
The library has to be built on a separate machine.

What I have tried (without success):

- putting the L.pdb next the A.exe
- adding a symbol path in Visual Studio to a folder containing the .pdb
- uploading the .pdb to a symbol server (which works for other libraries)
- adding the directory to the "Library Directories" in the project options
- Removing the symbol path in the final exe using PDBALTPATH, but that doesn't apply to static libraries.

The only things that worked are:

- linking L.lib directly to the main application, but that's not a solution as A shouldn't have to know about libraries used in the module M
- put the .pdb into a local folder using the exact same path as the original machine, i.e. D:\thirdparty\L\... This is obviously not a solution but shows that Visual Studio can load the symbols using the hard coded path in the PDB.

It looks like there is something wrong with using a static library inside an other one, or maybe it's a VS bug.

Has anyone encountered something like this and know how to solve it?

Cheers

Comment: As far as I know, the static libraries does not have a pdb file associated with them (when debugging). The code being added to the main application exe, the symbols are also merged with the main. I think the problem lies with the build of M library. Did you try to put the pdb of the L lib in the same folder as the lib itself? When you debug A, can you step into code from M?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and tips. I've put the L.pdb next to the M.lib in the output folder M\Win32\Debug\lib and it worked! That's great!
M is a module part of the main application so built at the same time and I can step into it.
Now the question is how to tell VS where to find the L.pdb as L is a thirdparty library and in a different folder. The place it has to be at the moment is a temporary build folder, so I don't really want to call a script to copy it there before building. In the references properties I can see M and its full absolute path, I suppose VS look for pdb next to it.